# CKEditor folder system

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory, ckeditor

I have a folder system on my server and now I'm trying to use these files with CKEditor.

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
     config.language = 'ru';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/admin/file/browser/';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/admin/file/uploader/';

};
```

As far as I understand this part of the code `config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/admin/file/browser/';`
creates and instance of CKEditor. And I can load files ONLY from root folder (for ex. `/Admin/File/Browser?path=picture_1920x1080.jpg`). When I go to a subfolder CKEditor doesn't work.
What can I do with that? Is there any way to reassign`config.filebrowserBrowseUrl`to the path I'm on?

There is my script for using files

```
<script src="~/Areas/Admin/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getUrlParam(paramName) {
            var reParam = new RegExp('(?:[\?&]|&)' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i');
            var match = window.location.search.match(reParam);

            return (match && match.length > 1) ? match[1] : null;
        }

        var funcNum = getUrlParam('ckEditorFuncNum');

        $(function() {
            $(".file").click(function() {
                var self = this;
                var fileUrl = $(self).attr("rel");
                window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, fileUrl);
                window.close();
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
```